# Are there list building macros in PGF/Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach

In Mathematica, C# linq, or other languages, we can use auxiliary functions to produce list of certain pattern.

For example:

1. In Mathematica, we can use `Table[]` or `Range[]` to produce a list of numbers in the specified pattern.
2. In C#, we can also use `Range` to produce a list of consecutive integers.

I need this kind of function also in PGF/Tikz to be consumed by `\foreach`.

Are there list building macros in PGF/Tikz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TikZ's `\foreach` accepts a lot of abbreviated lists. Examples include

- `\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6} {\x, }` yields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
- `\foreach \x in {1,3,...,11} {\x, }` yields 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,
- `\foreach \x in {Z,X,...,M} {\x, }` yields Z, X, V, T, R, P, N,
- `\foreach \x in {0\pi,0.5\pi,...\pi,3\pi} {$\x$, }` yields 0π, 0.5π, 1π, 1.5π, 2π, 2.5π, 3π,

For more details see “Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement“ in the TikZ manual (its Chapter 56 in the v2.10 manual).

Comment: thanks for answering. `{1/a/Z,2/b/Y,...,26/z/A}` is also possible ?

Comment: I think not. At least the manual doesn't say anything about it and it doesn't work in any obvious way.